# BigCommerce Stencil docs theme_images is empty

Tags: bigcommerce

Following the examples on the stencil documentation
https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/customizing-javascript

```
{{inject 'themeImageSizes' theme_images}}
```

Is added to the template, product.html and

```
console.log(this.context.themeImageSizes);
```

Is added to the product.js file.

However the console is logging an empty array. 
Where is or where should theme_images be defined?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure theme_images should be defined in config.json, but I think the Stencil docs may have the wrong reference here.

If you look at the YAML at the top of product.html, there are references there to values in config.json:

```
product:
    videos:
        limit: {{theme_settings.productpage_videos_count}}
    reviews:
        limit: {{theme_settings.productpage_reviews_count}}
    related_products:
        limit: {{theme_settings.productpage_related_products_count}}
    similar_by_views:
        limit: {{theme_settings.productpage_similar_by_views_count}}
```

The corresponding values in config.json are `settings.productpage_videos_count`, `settings.productpage_reviews_count`,  `settings.productpage_related_products_count`, and `settings.productpage_similar_by_views_count`.

So, my guess is that to reference the image sizes you should use this:

```
{{inject 'themeImageSizes' theme_settings._images}}
```

or maybe

```
{{inject 'themeImageSizes' theme_settings_images}}
```

However, I haven't been able to test that, so you might need to experiment. (I would have tested it but when I make changes to any file in assets/js the changes don't show up on any served pages from my dev server).